# Visual Studio Code Gradle binaries & hot code problem

Tags: java, gradle

So, I have a Java project using Gradle. When I import its **folder** into VSCode, **everything works**; the application can be launched, and most importantly, **the "bin" folder** containing all the compiled classes **is present**. (This allows me to use HotCode Replace.)
However, when I import the project via a **workspace** (through a **.code-workspace** file), the "bin" folder is not created, the **application can be launched** but HotCode Replace doesn't work.

N.B :

- HotCode Replace doesn't work if the "bin" folder is already present.
- Gralde version : 8.5
- JDK 17, Adoptium
- VSCode version : 1.85.2 (Latest)
- Gradle extention : 3.13.5 (Latest)

I tried some basic things:

- I've tested to import a project **without Gradle** (Empty Project) and **it work perfectly in both cases**.
- I've created another **empty gradle project** and it **doesn't work too**.
- I've tried to clean up the Java Lang. Server, `gradle clean` & `gradle --refresh-dependencies` (Just in case)
- I've tried to **disable all extention** (Excepted Java Pack) and the result : No changes

Here's the two videos for both cases (One inside a workspace and the other one as folder)

- https://youtu.be/Tstor0bxmlI -> folder
- https://youtu.be/pljc-iAssvE -> workspace

Hoping someone can assist me. :)

Comment: Perhaps try [*Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/)?